# Windows 7 On Domain Access Ubuntu Shared Folder

Tags: windows-7, samba

Had the samba setup done and when W7 access using \ip_address\share it prompts but only allow domain name login.

How should i go about it without dropping out W7 from domain?

Comment: anyone has any idea?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah managed to resolve after found this article http://blink4blog.blogspot.com/2012/02/fedora-16-post-installation-guide-mount.html although is for Fedora but it works for Ubuntu as well.